# numpy transformation 2d to 3d

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I m working on audio stuff with python and I have the data into a 2d array with left and right channels in two different dimensions

so my array shape looks like this (exemple) :

(360448, 2)

I'm trying to find a way to reshape the array so the data fits into a 3d array where each cell represent each sample in this way : [left_sample,right_sample,0] so the final array will have shape (X,X,3)

is there a way to reshape the array( without iterating and assigning the values) ?

Comment: numpy reshape should be what you are looking for. Something like np.reshape(array,360448/3,2,3). In this case you need to be sure that your initial array can be devided exactly by your new measures.

Comment: @Alessandro yes I think reshape should handle this but I tried many variations and always getting errors like ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged

Comment: That's because 360448/3 isn't an integer. As I said, you need to make sure your initial array can indeed be diveded into your final result

Comment: the integer is not the only problem I guess : a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]); b = np.reshape(a,(3,2,1)) . b contains [1,2],[3,4],[5,6] what I want is [1,4],[2,5],[3,6]

Comment: For that you can play with the axis, for instance b1 = np.reshape(a,(1,2,3)) gives you the result you want